# Safely Stopping MySQL Server on Windows Server

Tags: mysql, windows

Is stopping MySQL Process with `net stop MySQL57` safe? We are running MySQL Server on Windows Server and would like to backup whole server with file-system approach. If we would use `net stop MySQL57` would it not cause any database corruption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `net stop` and then `net start` is equivalent to using the services applet in the Windows control panel.

`net stop` also causes the service's dependent services (if any) to stop and restart.  For example, IIS Admin depends on World Wide Web, NNTP, FTP and SMTP if you have those installed and running.

`net stop` causes the services to shutdown "properly" and re-read the Windows registry before starting again.  It's the same as restarting safely.  Use the service names and not the display names (which won't work anyway).

You can also use the service controller app `sc` as well as `net start/net stop`.

You can see (or should see, if it installed properly) the MySQL service in the registry along with all others under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\`.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: In other words, yes it's safe to use net stop. :)

Comment: This question is more about MySQL which is a very complex thing rather than stopping processes.

Comment: Yes that's right.  MySQL is careful to start, stop, pause and restart in the Windows environment, digging down to its Nt Service class.  It's aware of whether mysqld was spawned by a Windows service or not, and includes an extensive test suite.  If the software malfunctioned in this environment I am sure it would be fixed quickly.  I think you can be confident that MySQL starts up and shuts down safely in the Windows environment, GUI or command line controlled.  Or as confident as you reasonably can be.  Running your own test cases is one way to be sure.

Comment: This seems like a better solution https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/05/07/prepare-mysql-for-a-safe-shutdown/